# Recording Audio on website: Red5 stream or posting the audio data?

Tags: php, flash, audio, ffmpeg, red5

Let me first establish what I want to do:

My user is able to record voicenotes on my website, add tags to said notes for indexing as well as a title. When the note is saved I save the path of the note along with the other info in my DB.

Now, I have 2 choices to do the recording, both involve a .swf embedded in my site:

1) I could use Red5 server to stream the audio to my server and save the file and return the path to said file to my app to do the DB saving, seems rather complicated since I would have to convert the audio and move it to the appropriate folder that belongs to the user in a server side Red5 app, which I'm not very aware of how to build.

2) I could simply record the audio and grab its byte array, do a Base64 encoding on it and send it to PHP along with the rest of the data that is necessary (be it by a simple POST or an AJAX call), decode it on the server and make the file with the appropriate extension, audio conversion would also occur here using ffmpeg, this option seems simpler but I do not know how viable it is.

What option would you say is more viable and easier to develop? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the planned duration of the recording, you may very well be able to use option number two. I recently used a similar approach successfully for a project, but recordings were only up to 30 seconds or so. Here's what I did differently from what you're suggesting though, and why I think it's better:

- To capture the sound from the microphone and store it to a ByteArray, use the [SAMPLE_DATA](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#event:sampleData) event which is dispatched whenever more sound data comes in from the microphone. There's an example in the documentation that should explain this well enough.
- Because most users would be on normal home computers without any special recording equipment, it was safe to assume that the full fidelity of the recording is not necessary. I used just 2 bytes per sample, and only mono, instead of using the full 64 bit floats (AS3 `Number`) that you get from the microphone on the `SAMPLE_DATA` event. Simply read the `Number` and do `myFloatSample * 0x7fff` to convert to 16 bit signed integer.
- Don't use the native 44.1kHz sampling rate if you're just recording speech or something else in that frequency range. You will likely get away just fine with 22.05kHz, which will cut the amount of data in half straight away. Just set the `Microphone.rate` property accordingly.
- Don't use Base64 to encode your data. Send it as binary data, which will be significantly smaller. You can send it as raw POST data, or using something like AMF. Also, before you send it, use the native `compress()` or `deflate()` methods on the ByteArray to compress it. On the server, decompress using the ZLIB or raw DEFLATE (inflate) algorithms respectively, which [PHP supports](https://www.php.net/zlib).
- Once decompressed on the server, what you have is essentially what is called a raw 16-bit mono PCM stream. Incidentally, that should be one of the very input formats that ffmpeg (or lame) supports, so you should be able to encode it to mp3 without having to do any manual decoding first.

Obviously the Red5 solution will likely be better, because it's more tailored for the task. But if you don't have the resources to set up a Red5 server, or don't want to use Java, the above solution is proven to work well as long as you stay away from too long recordings.

To take a simple example, a 30 second recording at 22,050 samples per second, 2 bytes per sample will be ~1.3MB. Even once deflated, the transfer to the server will likely still be almost a megabyte for 30 seconds of audio. This may or may not be acceptable for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the response, seems like a very complete solution. Though the file size seems a bit large. It's weird because with Red5 recording both audio and video the flv file ended up being about 400K for 20 seconds of audio and video. Now the thing is, how can I get the audio stream from flash? It seems that it's impossible unless you use a server like FMS or Red5, how did you manage to capture it?

Comment: Forgot to mention I want to allow recordings of up to 2 min, for now

Comment: Re capturing sound, I'm editing my response above. The file size when streaming is so small because the audio is destructively encoded on the client-side (e.g. using MP3). You might want to consider doing this on the client side in AS3 as well, but I doubt that with the time it takes to encode on such a slow system, the net effect will probably be that it takes longer than just sending the PCM.

Comment: That sounds good, I want it to be as small as possible but not losing so much quality as to make it intelligible. Would it be too much of a problem if I showed you my code and you helped me refine it as you say? I'm not very savvy with the whole sound thing. I'm able to record my sound and post it to a PHP file on my computer, and it plays fine, the deal is just the size right now, right now I have it set to 44100 samples, if I try to change it to 22k I turn into a chipmunk

Comment: If the sound is pitched (or rather, sped) up when you play it back, that's because you are not playing it at 22k. Make sure your PHP script saves it with the proper headers (what format are you using?) to indicate that the sample rate is 22kHz.

Comment: It's not when I save but when I play it back, and well when it saves it saves fine, with some interference, this is my code http://pastebin.com/rZrwXcJM

Comment: If you change the mic rate and rate variable in my encode method to 44  it does proper playback, but the saved file still has some interference

Comment: I would really appreciate some help with this

Comment: The player (whatever you're using) will play it back at whatever framerate that the file format dictates that it should use. Hence, the mistake is definitely in the writing. How are you saving it to disk? What format are you using? Make sure that you are using a format that supports 22kHz mono, and that you are properly indicating the sample rate in the file header.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about playing it back inside Flash? Using your playerHandler function? All audio playback in Flash has to be 44.1K, so you have to make sure that you pad with extra data in that event handler: First add the sample, then add the average between the current sample and the next, before moving on to add the next one.

Comment: It plays sped up in iTunes that I also test it there, I save it as a .wav file and it plays with some errors, any changes I can make to the code I showed you to fix my problems? The speeding up, the errors and the portability.